# onblur ajax not calling the callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I Have the following code which is called inline as below also. The problem is the alert never fires. In firebug i can see that data is filled with my object, but still the alert doesn't fire. Any ideas?

```
function update(s_arrive) {
    $.post("../base/getDestInfo.asp", { "dest": s_arrive }, function(data) { alert('aa'); }, "json");
}

<input type='text' name="box" onblur="update('AUS');" />
```

**Update:**
One thing that does work is if I make the request synchronis then its fires.

**Update2:**
IE 8 & Chrome works as expected. Firefox however...not so much.

**Update3:**
After restarting Firefox it worked. Very very very very weird.
Closing item.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you refresh the page while stepping in the firebird debugger, scripts stop in that tab, I often have to open the page in another tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try again removing the semicolon. It works for me sometimes.

```
<input type='text' name="box" onblur="update('AUS')" />
```